# CSS Marquee speed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Using CSS for a marquee effect, the code is running perfect. My only issue is speed.

When the text is short the marquee takes longer. When the text is long the marquee runs very quickly. I know the above is because of the animation time `animation: marquee 15s linear infinite;`

Is there a way to run the marquee at a consistent speed no matter the text length?
I am open to use Javascript if needed (I have tried but not succeeded.)

Here is my current CSS code:

```
<style>
    /* Make it a marquee */
    .marquee {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #000000;
        bottom: 0px;
        color: white;
    }
    .marquee span {
        display: inline-block;
        padding-left: 100%;
        text-indent: 0;
        animation: marquee 15s linear infinite;
        animation-delay: 10s;
        background-color: #000000;
        color: white;
        bottom: 0px;
    }
    /* Make it move */

    @keyframes marquee {
        0% {
            transform: translate(10%, 0);
        }
        100% {
            transform: translate(-100%, 0);
        }
    }
    /* Make it pretty */

    .scroll {
        padding-left: 1.5em;
        position: fixed;
        font: 50px 'Verdana';
        bottom: 0px;
        color: white;
        left: 0px;
        height: 10%;
    }
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="marquee">
<p class="scroll marquee"><span id="scrolltext"></span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Just a note: Javascript has nothing to do with Java except some basic similarities in syntax.

Comment: Could you also post your HTML?

Comment: @Charles Tester where is the html code.?

Comment: @HimeshAadeshara - HTML was added

Comment: @Charles Tester some detail added you can check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right, this is more of a math problem than anything.

We can do a simple `Time = Distance/Speed` calculation like this

```js
function calcSpeed(speed) {
  // Time = Distance/Speed
  var spanSelector = document.querySelector('.marquee span');
  var spanLength = spanSelector.offsetWidth;
  var timeTaken = spanLength / speed;
  spanSelector.style.animationDuration = timeTaken + "s";
}
calcSpeed(100);

function calcFastSpeed(speed) {
  // Time = Distance/Speed
  var spanSelector = document.querySelector('.fast.marquee span');
  var spanLength = spanSelector.offsetWidth;
  var timeTaken = spanLength / speed;
  spanSelector.style.animationDuration = timeTaken + "s";
}
calcFastSpeed(500);
```

```css
/* Make it a marquee */

.marquee {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #000000;
  bottom: 0px;
  color: white;
}
.marquee span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 100%;
  text-indent: 0;
  animation: marquee linear infinite;
  animation-delay: 5s;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: white;
  bottom: 0px;
}
/* Make it move */

@keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    transform: translate(10%, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  }
}
/* Make it pretty */

.scroll {
  padding-left: 1.5em;
  position: fixed;
  font: 50px'Verdana';
  bottom: 0px;
  color: white;
  left: 0px;
  height: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="marquee">
  <span>Lots of text, written in a long sentence to make it go off the screen. Well I hope it goes off the screen</span>
</div>
<br />
<div class="fast marquee">
  <span>Lots of text, written in a long sentence to make it go off the screen. Well I hope it goes off the screen</span>
</div>
```

Of course, this is a simple example that doesn't take into account how long the 'track' is, but now you know the basics I'm sure you can work it out :-)

Here is another example with 2 different lengths of text traveling at the same speed

```js
function calcSpeed(speed) {
  // Time = Distance/Speed
  var spanSelector = document.querySelectorAll('.marquee span'),
    i;
  for (i = 0; i < spanSelector.length; i++) {
    var spanLength = spanSelector[i].offsetWidth,
      timeTaken = spanLength / speed;
    spanSelector[i].style.animationDuration = timeTaken + "s";
  }
}
calcSpeed(100);
```

```css
/* Make it a marquee */

.marquee {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #000000;
  bottom: 0px;
  color: white;
}
.marquee span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 100%;
  text-indent: 0;
  animation: marquee linear infinite;
  animation-delay: 5s;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: white;
  bottom: 0px;
}
/* Make it move */

@keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    transform: translate(10%, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  }
}
/* Make it pretty */

.scroll {
  padding-left: 1.5em;
  position: fixed;
  font: 50px'Verdana';
  bottom: 0px;
  color: white;
  left: 0px;
  height: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="marquee">
  <span>Lots of text, written in a long sentance to make it go off the screen. Well I hope it goes off the screen</span>
</div>
<br />
<div class="marquee">
  <span>Well I hope it goes off the screen</span>
</div>
```

Comment: @CharlesTester like this you mean? http://jsfiddle.net/link2twenty/oxw4e5yh/1/ I removed the animation-delay and had it start at 0 as oppose to 10% (in the translate)

Answer (score 0):

You can give your sliding element the same width, then they should scroll with the same speed. But it´s not really dynamic.

Or you can calculate the speed depending on the width of the element. See my small demo.

```js
// your time for 10 px in seconds
var timeFor10Px = 0.2;
var animationSettings = 'marquee linear infinite';
var $marque = $('.marque');

$marque.each( function() {
  var outerWidth = $(this).outerWidth();
  var calc = outerWidth / 10 * timeFor10Px;
  $(this).css('animation', animationSettings + ' ' + calc + 's');
});
```

```css
.holder {
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
}

.marque {
  /* removed, see js tab */
  /*animation: marquee 15s linear infinite; */
  display: inline-block;
}



@keyframes marquee {
  from {
    transform: translate( 0%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translate( 100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="holder">
  <span class="marque marqu1">
  Some nice Text
  </span>
  <br>
  <span class="marque marqu2">
  Some nice Text Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet.....
  </span>
</div>
```

edit: @Andrew Bones was a little bit faster, with the similar solution

Answer (score -1):

hi here is the example you are trying to do [Example](https://codepen.io/jamesbarnett/pen/kfmKa)

and more if you can provide proper HTML code Details with the question

```css
body { margin: 20px; }

.marquee {
  height: 25px;
  width: 420px;

  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.marquee div {
  display: block;
  width: 200%;
  height: 30px;

  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;

  animation: marquee 5s linear infinite;
}

.marquee span {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  0% { left: 0; }
  100% { left: -100%; }
}
```

```html
<div class="marquee">
  <div>
    <span>You spin me right round, baby. Like a record, baby.</span>
    <span>You spin me right round, baby. Like a record, baby.</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hii it's look like it's working proper with

```css
 @keyframes marquee {
        0% {
            transform: translate(10%, 0);
        }
        100% {
            transform: translate(-100%, 0);
        }
   }

-------- i used belowed one that works fine for me ----------
------------------ you can try thisss---------------------

@keyframes marquee {
        0% {
            transform: translate(0%, 0);
        }
        100% {
            transform: translate(-100%, 0);
        }
   }
```